# What is the Jquery compatible version for Bootstrap 4.0.0

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, jquery-ui, bootstrap-4

Please suggest the compatible version of jquery to be used with Bootstrap version 4.0.0
Also just for knowledge,  list out the versions of bootstrap and Jquery which works to together

Any suggestions or reference
Thanks

Comment: [**Read the documentation**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#breaking) "Bootstrap still requires jQuery 1.9.1 or higher, but you’re advised to use version 3.x since v3.x’s supported browsers are the ones Bootstrap supports plus v3.x has some security fixes."

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#js

Comment: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/package.json#L87

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Bootstrap 4.3 has a breaking change on how the navbar menus are created. Use an earlier version instead.**

Try the following code taken from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#navbar in https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_gs_container&stacked=h and you can see the result

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: how much early of the version I should use?

Comment: @Sam So far BS 4.5 works with jquery-1.12.4.min.js