# Is it possible to add the latest version of bootstrap to widgets that use jquery version 2.1.3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, jquery-plugins, bootstrap-modal

I have a chatbot widget. It use jquery version 2.1.3. The widget is not used bootstrap. So I want add bootstrap. Because I want to add feature modal feedback on the widget

I see on https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/, the version latest of bootstrap is version 4

Is it possible to add bootstrap version 4 to my widget that use jquery version 2.1.3?

Comment: "Bootstrap still requires jQuery 1.9.1 or higher, but you’re advised to use version 3.x since v3.x’s supported browsers are the ones Bootstrap supports plus v3.x has some security fixes" ref: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#breaking & ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50603669/what-is-the-jquery-compatible-version-for-bootstrap-4-0-0

Comment: @Akber Iqbal what do you mean by version 3? Bootstrap version 3 or jquery version 3?

Comment: for bootstrap4... it is advised to use jQuery version 3 and up....

Comment: @Akber Iqbal for this case I have to keep using jquery version 2.1.3. I will not replace it. because it will change a lot code. in this case I can only replace the bootstrap version. no problem using the version under bootstrap 4

Comment: Sounds about right - best to test the critical components on high-volume and high-priority pages too. Good luck

Comment: @Akber Iqbal I have added bootstrap version 4 to the widget with jquery version 2.1.3 and that is no problem